# How to append td with last-child jquery?

Tags: jquery, html-table, mouseenter

I created the following code:

```
<table id="map">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table> 

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('td:last-child').mouseenter(function(){
            var tdId = $(this).attr('id');
            var newId = parseInt(tdId);
            $(this).after('<td>new</td>');
        });         
    });
</script>
```

I want to create a new `td` when the mouse enter on last-child the tds. That code is working. but when I want to create a new td again I must hover on `<td>3</td>` not on last `td` that create automatically!  How can I fix that?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use event delegation instead of binding the handlers directly to the `td` elements:

```
$('#map').on('mouseenter', 'td:last-child', function(){
   // code here
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DyTpJ/

Comment: `'td:last-child', function(){`